# Factorization for finite simplicial sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, model-categories

Consider the category of simplicial sets with the Quillen model structure.

Let $f:X \to Y$ a map of finite simplicial sets. By the small object argument, we can write $f=pi$ where $p:Z \to Y$ is a fibration, $i:X \to Z$ is a cofibration and either $p$ or $i$ is trivial. Can we do that in a way so that $Z$ is finite simplicial set as well?

Using the cylinder object $X \times [1]$, I can furnish a factorization $X \to (X \times [1]) \coprod_{X} Y \to Y$ where the second map is a weak equivalence and the first is a cofibration. Unfortunately, there is no reason in general why the second map would be a fibration. A dual argument shows, we can factor $f$ as a weak equivalence followed by a fibration where the weak equivalence might not be a confibration.

So, my question is, can we actually do that? In other words, if we keep most axioms for a model category but drop the existence of colimits/limits, would the usual model structure on Simplicial Sets restrict to a model structure on the finite ones?

Comment: The problem is that you need at least some limits and colimits if you want the theory to work and do what you desire. I think some authors only require finite limits and colimits, but I really don't think you can ask less and end up with a theory that's still useful...

Comment: Finite colimits or limits are probably fine since I think finite simplicial sets are closed under those. It seems the factorization uses though at least countable sequential colimits for the small object argument to work and I was wondering if you can circumvent that somehow.